# Zend Log: Unexplained Error On Page Request

Tags: zend-framework

I'm working on a very custom project using the Zend Framework, where the application uses database driven routes, default routes disabled by default, and a module setup.

I've just created a Zend_Log writer, that logs application errors in the Database.

The thing is, I've got two unexplained errors:

```
5 NOTICE M:\Zend_Framework\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php Line 516 Page not found
5 NOTICE M:\Zend_Framework\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php Line 516 Request Parameters
```

I've had a look at the line in question and it just has `$this->$action();`, which doesn't help me!

Can anyone tell me how I can debug this further?

Comment: I have always wondered about this error!

Answer (score 0):

These are not complete errors. Your logging is somehow broken. We did something like this for our project earlier - you can as well log get/post params, stacktrace, etc.

This looks like someone request nonexistent action - something like /index/does-not-exist